# Retrieve the full name of a service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

By default,according to [k8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), Services are assigned a DNS A record for a name of the form `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example`.

Is there a command to retrieve the full name of a service?

Comment: nslookup service name will give you this

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can do a DNS query from any pod and you would get the FQDN.

```
# nslookup api-server
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   api-server.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.104.225.18

root@api-server-6ff8c8b9c-6pgkb:/#
```

`cluster-domain.example` is just a example in the documentation. `cluster.local` is the default cluster domain assigned. So the FQDN of any service by default would be `<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`.

You don't need to use the FQDN to access services - for services in same namespace, just the service name would be enough. For services in other namespaces, `<service-name>.<namespace>` would be enough as kubernetes would automatically set up the DNS search domains.

Comment: Lets say that I have the service db-service running in `-n dev` and `-n prod`. I know that the FQDN would be `db-service.dev.svc.cluster.local` and `db-service.prod.svc.cluster.local` respectively, but how would I use the nslookup in this scenario?

Comment: You need to know the namespace at least. You can do `nslookup db-service.dev` or `nslookup db-service.prod`

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong, cause the only result that I'm able to get is: `** server can't find xxx: NXDOMAIN`, where xxx is the service name.

Comment: Where are you running the nslookup command? You should be running it inside a container in a pod.

Comment: It worked, thanks @aviator.`master $ kubectl exec -it redis -- nslookup redis-service.default
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      redis-service.default
Address 1: 10.107.229.159 redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: My pod doesn't have nslookup ...

Comment: Note that `api-server` is actually the name of the service in the node, and not a constant command

Answer (score 15):

**TLDR; skip the below if you just want an automated way to do this; here's a quick bash script I wrote to do this automatically. This assumes bash is installed in the container:**

```bash
k8s_shell_pod_svc_nslookup () {
  kubectl exec -it $1 --container $2 -- /bin/bash -c "apt update;apt-get -y install dnsutils;nslookup $3"
}
```

**Sample use:**

```
k8s_shell_pod_svc_nslookup example_pod example_container example_service
```

---

Longer Explanation:

First, get the name of the service you're interested in getting the FQDN (fully qualified domain name) for by listing all of your services in the appropriate namespace:

```zsh
kubectl get svc -n <namespace>
```

Second, get the name of the pod associated with the service you're interested in by listing all of your pods:

```zsh
kubectl get pods
```

Third, get the container in the pod you're interested in by listing all of the containers in that pod:

```zsh
kubectl get pods <pod_name> -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[*].name}'
```

Fourth, you need to access the pod (and the container running in the pod) and start a bash shell. Note: I use Istio, so I'll always have multiple containers running in my pods, so I also specify my container. This assumes bash is installed in the container.

```sh
kubectl exec -it <pod_name> --container <container_name> -- /bin/bash
```

Fifth, once your bash shell has started, if you're running a `debian` container, you'll need to use `apt` to install `dnsutils` before you do the nslookup. If you're not using `debian`, use the appropriate alternative:

```zsh
apt update && apt-get -y install dnsutils
```

Sixth, you can perform the `nslookup`:

```
nslookup <service_name>
```