# How to access pods in same node? (Helm)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have two charts in helm.

```
Chart A (service.type=LoadBalancer)
Chart B (service.type=NodePort)
```

*Env of Chart A has uri of Chart B*

*Env of Chart B has uri of Chart A*

When I install Chart A with env (URI of chart B), it gives dynamic node ip and node port for chart A.
Then I install Chart B with env (URI of chart A), it gives dynamic node ip and node port for chart B.

**But old node ip and node port of Chart B is present in the chart A env.**

If I update it in chart A env and reinstall, it gives new dynamic node ip and node port for chart A which is not present in chart B.

Is there any possible way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `IP address` as `env`, use the service's DNS address.

Let's say, Chart-A has a service named `service-A` on namespace `demo`. You can connect to `service-A` from any namespace of the cluster on `service-A.demo.svc`. You don't need to worry while upgrading or reinstalling Chart-A, just make sure that the service's name remains the same.

URL formal: `<service-name>.<namespace>.svc:PORT`

Comment: Thankyou @Kamol Hasan
Initially I didn't aware of service DNS. We can access any service through DNS if service.type is clusterIP and clusterIP is set to be None `clusterIP: None`
 _Related links:_
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59559438/retrieve-the-full-name-of-a-service-in-kubernetes]
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/]

Comment: @vignesh5698 when you use the DNS address of a headless service (`clusterIP: None`), it returns a set of IPs. So, you need to handle this case too.